# remotes::install_github Error: HTTP error 422. No commit found for SHA: rc-0.3.1

Tags: r, http, github, xaringan, remotes

I'm not able to install any package from `github`. When I tried the following code

```
remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan', upgrade = TRUE)
```

I got the following message

```
Downloading GitHub repo yihui/xaringan@master
Error: HTTP error 422.
  No commit found for SHA: rc-0.3.1

  Rate limit remaining: 4990/5000
  Rate limit reset at: 2019-02-22 11:49:24 UTC
```

Any thoughts to figure out this problem, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/273. Try this instead:

```
remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan', upgrade = FALSE)
```

Since the offending package seems to be **rlang** (which you previously installed from Github but a certain branch named `rc-0.3.1` has been deleted later), you need to reinstall it from CRAN.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui for your answer. However `remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan', upgrade = FALSE)` throws the same error.

Comment: I guess the offending package here is **rlang** (installed from Github). You can try to install it from CRAN instead.

Comment: Re-instalation of  **rlang**  from CRAN and then using `remotes::install_github('yihui/xaringan', upgrade = TRUE)` worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm having the same error for several github packages, but not all, updating rlang or using the above didn't work.